# Create an excel/word document using SPFX web part in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, excel, word, create-document

I have one requirement about preparing excel and word document based on SharePoint list data and download it for user in SharePoint Online using SPFX web part.

**My question is:** Can we create SPFx web part in which it creates a document using code and download it from web part? OR even is it possible with SPFx web part to create a document using coding?

Answer (score 1):

SPFx works using client-side JavaScript, meaning you can utilize any solutions out there that employ JavaScript.

For Word documents, you could use [this tutorial](https://effectiveinc.com/effective-thinking/articles/generating-downloadable-word-document-browser/) explaining how to generate a Word document from some basic HTML, and download it using an `a` element.

For Excel documents, you could create a CSV file (a basic spreadsheet) using a similar method in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17836273/export-javascript-data-to-csv-file-without-server-interaction/17836529#17836529).